# An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module

Tags: angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen al ejecutar `ng serve` me esta generando este error en la consola de visual no se que pueda ser el problema, por favor ¿Podrían ayudarme con una orientación?

> *An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module C:\Vespot-Daniel\Aplicativo_Vespotgo\ProyectoInterno\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js from C:\Vespot-Daniel\Aplicativo_Vespotgo\ProyectoInterno\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js not supported.
> Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Vespot-Daniel\Aplicativo_Vespotgo\ProyectoInterno\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> See "C:\Users\jusei\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-8LSehh\angular-errors.log" for further details.*

este es mi paquete json

```js
{
  "name": "proyecto-vespot",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jeb": "^0.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  }
}
```

y este es mi archivo de angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ProyectoVespot": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ProyectoVespot",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ProyectoVespot:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ProyectoVespot:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ProyectoVespot:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ProyectoVespot"
}
```

para solucionarlo me recomendaron nombrar la carpeta `node_modules` por `node_modules_old` , practicamente eso hice , cerre visual studio y lo volvi a brir , luego ejecute `npm install`  en la consola del proyecto y me voto estos errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ultimo con `ng serve`  ahora me genero este siguiente error no se que podria a hacer para que compile correctamente y pueda iniciar el proyecto, me tiene mirando toda la mañana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel Andrés! Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/509128/edit) la pregunta añadiendo tus archivos de configuración (package.json y angular.json) para tener algo más de información e intentar ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: Buenos dias muchas gracias por la respuesta , ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: He creado nuevo proyecto poniendo tus archivos de configuración y al hacer `ng-serve` me ha funcionado bien. He mirado la ruta `node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js`y no existe en mi proyecto. Como prueba te diría que renombres tu carpeta `node_modules` por otro nombre (por ejemplo `node_modules_old`) y lances un `npm install` desde la raíz de tu proyecto. A ver si es cosa de que se ha quedado algo "raruno". Luego prueba de nuevo con `ng-serve`. A ver si es esto 

Comment: No te he dicho en el comentario de antes. Parece como si en la carpeta `build-angular` se te hubiese metido una versión antigua de `node_modules`, por eso creo que haciendo lo anterior te puede funcionar. Y el comando a lanzar es `ng serve` que se ha coldao un guión entre medias

Comment: ok te agradezco mucho , que raro me aparece un mensaje de error que dice que no me permite renombrarlo intentare desde el explorador

Comment: Aplique lo que me dijiste en lo anterior renombre la carpeta + npm install + ng serve  al ejecutar npm install me aparece error y con ng serve me aparece este mensaje :                    $ ng serve
Node packages may not be installed. Try installing with 'npm install'.
Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.

Comment: Si no se ejecuta correctamente `npm install` no te funcionará `ng serve`. Error del comando `npm install`?

Comment: si exactamente es error del comando no lo estoy escribiendo mal , cuando lo ejecuto las dependencias que intenta instalar salen con error

Comment: Lo que quería decir es que cuál era el error que te mostraba al ejecutar `npm install`. Mira a ver no sea problema de permisos en la carpeta de tu proyecto. El usuario de la consola de visual studio code normalmente es diferente a tu usuario. De todas maneras, si no conseguimos arreglarlo luego edita la pregunta diciendo todo lo que has hecho de pruebas (así conseguirás que el resto de la comunidad vea que has intentado solucionarlo y estarán más dispuestos a echarte una mano)

Comment: Pues lo que te dice el error, que pongas los paquetes que están en versión 13.1.2 por 13.1.3 en el archivo package.json porque no son compatibles.

Comment: ok gracias muy amable

Comment: me sirvio cambiar la version muchas gracias

Comment: Te funciona entonces?? Me alegro! Se nos había resistido 